# Using a variable with a value assigned in a class's construct method else where without re assigning value

Tags: php, class, oop, mysqli

I have a basic class:

```
class Customer {

  private $customer_info;
  private $mysqli;

  function __construct(Array $customer_info, Mysqli $mysqli) {
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    $this->customer_info = $customer_info;
  }

}
```

In the construct method I assign a value to the mysqli and customer_info variables.

In every method I have to tell it what $mysqli is, but I feel like its just referencing itself.

```
public function get() {
  $mysqli = $this->mysqli;
  // carry out mysql things
}
```

If I don't include that line, then any statements etc do not work, is there anyway that I can do it so I don't have to keep doing $mysqli = $this->mysqli in every method?

Comment: why you don't youse $this->mysqli instead of $mysqli in each methode?

Comment: Makes sense :) Simple answers are the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No thats's not possible to access a class variable you should use `$this->myvar`, unless you use static variables than you can call variables like `self:$myvar`

Comment: Thats the answer i'm looking for :) Thanks.

Comment: @user2921557 pls aware ... if you would like to use self::$mysqli you must change $mysqli to **static** *private* $mysqli

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it

Make the variable public and static in class.

```
public static $mysqli;
```

And anywhere you can access static member like

```
$mysqli = Customer::mysqli;
```

But better is to make variable private and use it by calling method like.

```
public function getSQLConn() {
  $mysqli = $this->mysqli;
  return $mysqli;
}
```

And get value/use it like

```
$mysqli = $this->getSQLConn();
```